# Entity Framework select data from two tables in two different schemas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am trying to do a simple request with Entity Framework for my mvc4 application. I want to select data from two tables.

One table is inside the Membership Provider schema, while the other one is inside my main table. The SQL request is :

```
select users.my_aspnet_users.name, invitations.sender from users.my_aspnet_users, invitations where invitations.sender = my_aspnet_users.id;
```

I know how to select data for one table, but it looks different when dealing with two tables, especially when these tables are not in the same schema.

Moreover I have only generated the .edmx file (ie imported the schema) for the main schema. The Membership Provider shema is used directly by `System.Web.Security`.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think a complex type is your need